# Freely Draggable TextView - Fine Control

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a TextView with the id "tx". I've set an OnTouchListener to allow the user to drag the view.

```
tx.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getRawX();
        float y = event.getRawY();
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            // Offsets center the TextView to the center of the MotionEvent
            view.setX(x - view.getWidth() / 2);
            view.setY(y - view.getHeight() / 2);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

How can I create a dragging effect whereby wherever the user initially clicks, that position is the one where the dragging begins? I want fine control (identical to Snapchat or Autodesk Sketch) so if I decide to drag from the left, there is no re-centering. I think this is what most users expect from this kind of interaction. They don't want their TextView to be re-positioned at the center of where they first clicked.

All help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will always be an `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` preceded by `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`

You should first handle the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` event which will give you the position where the user first touched. You can store those coordinates and then use them in the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` to do whatever you want to do.

Comment: @pgitu Thanks for the suggestion! I managed to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out and so I'm posting the answer in full here as it was really frustrating finding help on what would seem to be such a simple problem. You basically need to set the initial x and y coordinates on the down press, then offset the the margins of the TextView by the a value equal to the TextView's current position +/- your initial input coordinates. This give the illusion of the moving the textview smoothly in the direction that you're dragging. I hope this helps someone!

```
TextView tx;        
tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

tx.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            int initialX = 0;
            int initialY = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = (int) event.getX();
                        initialY = (int) event.getY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int currentX = (int) event.getX();
                        int currentY = (int) event.getY();
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tx.getLayoutParams();

                        int left = lp.leftMargin + (currentX - initialX);
                        int top = lp.topMargin + (currentY - initialY);
                        int right = lp.rightMargin - (currentX - initialX);
                        int bottom = lp.bottomMargin - (currentY - initialY);

                        lp.rightMargin = right;
                        lp.leftMargin = left;
                        lp.bottomMargin = bottom;
                        lp.topMargin = top;

                        tx.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

And the layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:text=""
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
    android:textSize="48sp"
    android:textColor="#33ffcc" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why not use setX/setY on the textview? Then you don't need the right and bottom calculations